# Apollo GraphQL query refetch

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I'm trying to do a query refetch after a form submission using Apollo. I am trying to use this example: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#refetching

My query is:

```
const { data: accountData, loading: accountLoading, refetch: accountDataRefetch } = useGetUserSocialLoginQuery({ variables: { accountId: nrId } })
```

After the form submission I'm calling the refetch function:

```
const formSubmissionFunction = async () => {
  // update an UserSocialLogin entity
  await accountDataRefetch()
}
```

I've also tried to update the query result within the update mutation, but also without success. The UserSocialLogin entity is updated but the data object remains the same. The UI should display the new data.

Do you have any ideas?